# Нужно вывести элементы массива циклом в таблице

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

Есть база данных, в ней содержатся данные по объектам.
Необходимо в виде таблицы циклом вывести данные (5 значений из 50).
При этом по клику на строку выдавать (на отдельной странице) все данные по этому объекту, все 50 значений)
Как это можно реализовать? Особо не понятно как отслеживать клик по строке.
Желательно это делать в php, т.к. в javascript я не шарю вообще.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: ну если без js то строку делаете ссылкой, в параметрах которой передаете нужные данные (id какой нибудь) который понимает php и выдает информацию по объекту.

Comment: Спасибо, это определенно мне поможет, но как на базе строки-ссылки сделать приемлимую для глаз таблицу? Хотя бы что бы по ширине колонки совпадали с другими, т.к. данные там разной длинны хранятся. Пробовал сделать простой вывод переменных - их конечно разносит в разные места, совсем не так как надо, но выводятся все. Приписал туда <table> <tr> <td> - выводится одна переменная, в нужном месте, но игнорируя цикл.

Comment: ну если цикл игнорируется, видимо вы выводите <tr> не в цикле. посмотрите исходный код страницы (обычно Ctrl+U в браузере) которую создала ваша php и внимательно изучите что там нагенерилось, пройдитесь в уме по циклу, подумайте где что выводится. Как бы невозможно не видя кода сказать, почему у вас таблица может неправильно формироваться

Comment: <tr> в цикле, <td> в цикле, <table> вне цикла

Comment: приведите своё решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример таблицы

```
<?php
if (count($result) > 0): 
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($result))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($result as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row);?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
else : 
echo 'Пустая таблица';
endif;
```