# Как считать данные в переменные из БД (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть бд, которая выглядит так:
[image: БД]

Хочу из этой БД по steamID вернуть из функции visitors и favs(да, я вижу, что у меня return 0, у меня проблема с парсингом записи из базы). И что-то вот не получается :с

```
function loadOldData($funcSteamId) {
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev', 'root', 'root');

$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(steamID) FROM guidesStats WHERE steamID=:inputID");
$query->execute(array('inputID' => $funcSteamId));
$result = $query->fetchAll();

if ($result[0][0] == 1) {
    $affectedRows = $connection->exec('SELECT `visitors`,`favs` FROM `guidesStats` WHERE `steamID` = ' . $funcSteamId . '');

    if ($affectedRows) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
        echo '<table><tr>';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // Получаем строки из результата
            echo "<td>$row[login]</td>"; // и выводим их на страницу
        }
        echo '</tr></table>';
    } else {
        echo "пустой результат";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [ссылка на такой же вопрос и ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714294/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5/714415#714415)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` добавьте перед `$result = $query->fetchAll();`   Это позволит получать данные в виде ассоциативного массива.